# Динамические запросы с параметрами в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Курил документацию по MySQL и не до конца понял, как передавать аргументы в динамический запрос.

В MS SQL я мог через sp_executesql сказать

> Хочу, что бы @Param1 внутри запроса имел значение из @Val, а @Param2 из @Val2

Т.е я мог сопоставить руками.

Есть ли такая возможность в MySql? Все примеры, которые я нашел делают подстановку через символ `?` и как я понял это подстановка по позиции.

Процедура ~ такая:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `Test`(
IN TableName nvarchar(255),
IN Filter nvarchar(255)
)
BEGIN
SET @Query=CONCAT("
SELECT -1;
SELECT * FROM ",TableName," WHERE dbName='",Filter,"';

SELECT -1;
SELECT * FROM ",TableName," 
WHERE dbName='",Filter,"' AND Field=100500;");


SELECT @Query;
prepare PreparedQuery FROM @Query;
EXECUTE  PreparedQuery;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE PreparedQuery;

END
```

Comment: Может попробовать SET->PREPARE->execute, где в set передается строка запроса, куда передаются параметры val и val2? Просто ещё сделать дополнительный шаг, заэкзекутив присвоение переменных?

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev ну я пробовал через CONCAT агрегацию делать, но почему-то вот это i.dbName='",Filter,"' преобразуется в i.dbName=\'123qwe\' => не работает. Какие-то слеши появляются.

Comment: *Есть ли такая возможность в MySql?* Отож... `EXECUTE sp_name USING @param1, @param2, ...`. [Prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html), см. примеры, все три.

Comment: А код приложите, пожалуйста

Comment: @Akina т.е я могу написать что-то типа `execute @query USING @InnerParam1=@OuterParam1` ?

Comment: *я могу написать что-то типа `execute @query USING @InnerParam1=@OuterParam1` ?* - нет. Да и зачем? prepared statement не позволяет использовать пользовательские переменные в теле запроса - всё равно область видимости не та... И потом - а тебе не пофиг, какое имя у переменной внутри запроса?

Comment: @Akina а если я хочу, что бы определенные `?` брали значение из одной переменной? Это нужно дублировать переменную. Ну и подстановка по позиции не совсем нравится... =(

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev добавил.

Comment: Ну насколько я понимаю, только если до выполнения всех селектов пропишите SET`ы для всех переменных в теле запроса, тогда сможете потом в запросах как хотите вертеть. Но все равно до конца не понимаю цели вашей:) sp_executesql тоже ведь назначает явно значения для каждой переменной... Приведите пример того, как вы хотели б, чтобы это работало и почему сейчас не так

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev В общем, хочу из вне в процедуру передать название БД и фильтры. ЧТо бы это все подставилось в заранее заготовленный запрос и выполнилось.

Comment: *а если я хочу, что бы определенные ? брали значение из одной переменной?* Укажешь в параметрах EXECUTE 2 раза. Или сколько там надо.

Comment: @iluxa1810 ну вы когда передаете параметры, сделайте внутренние переменные (перед селектом пропишите сеты) в квери, где вы им задаете передаваемые значения, а дальше используйте по телу запроса эти внутренние переменные.

Comment: Я ж правильно понимаю, что цель - не проставлять во все значения `?` значения, а назначить лишь один раз?

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev типа того. Не люблю позиционку, особенно если запрос большой => нужно все высчитывать.

Comment: `SET @Query=CONCAT("SET @param1 = ?; SET @param2 = ? SELECT -1 FROM @param1;....`, а затем уже `EXECUTE sp_name USING @val1, @val2`?

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev а можно пример ответом? Вроде, сделал все четко, но нефига не пашет. На вход в процедуру передается название целевой таблицы, и таблицы источника, а так же фильтр. Нужно подставить в заранее заготовленный запрос в процедуре названия таблиц и сделать INSERT INTO записей, который фильтруются по переданному фильтру.

Comment: По крайней мере такое должно было пахать в MS SQL...